# "Ask questions of the past raised" or "Ask the past the questions raised"?

Tags: gerunds, objects

I read a following sentence:

> [Yet the stories they tell avoid any evolutionary model of progress, as well as any systematic critique. I want to outline, however rapidly, the history of the present moment in translation studies.]
> And to some degree this means asking questions of the past raised by the latest tendencies in theory and research.
>
> <sup>Source: Lawrence Venuti, "Introduction," in The Translation Studies Reader, 4th ed., New York: Routledge, 2021, p.2.</sup>

My question is about "of the past," especially its role and position.

1. Can it be paraphrased as "And to some degree this means **asking the past the questions** raised by the latest tendencies in theory and research"?
2. If it can be paraphrased as such, why did the author write "asking questions of the past raised..."?

Comment: What is the source of your quote?

Comment: Lawrence Venuti (ed.), The Translation Studies Reader. 4th ed. New York: Routledge, 2021.

Comment: The passage is lovely as is. Your edit is okay. The original is poetic yet clear, and that's a sweet spot for many a reader.

Comment: > Baskin, thanks for your comment. Is it grammatically ok that putting "of the past" between "questions" and its modifier "raised by..."?

Comment: Generally 3-place predicates don't do Dative Alternation if the receiver is not human. _The past_ is a very abstract noun phrase, and _ask questions of the past_ is a metaphoric rendering. Would you like _I asked the past questions about it, and came up with the following answers_ ?

Comment: > Lawler, thank you for your technical comment. Your suggestion sounds good to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it can be paraphrased as such, although I would leave out the article before "questions", since that implies it is an exhaustive list of questions, and not just some of them.
2. We can't know for certain why the author would have phrased it like that, but Lawrence Venuti probably preferred presenting it like this because leading that clause with "*this means asking questions of the past*" accentuates that element of outlining without going into details of how these questions are raised.

Comment: Joachim, thank you so much. It helped a lot!

Comment: @Lemon Asking questions of the past isn't the same as asking the past questions. It may simply mean asking questions ABOUT the past.

Comment: > tchrist, thanks for your comment. If "asking questions _of_ the past" means "asking questions _about_ the past," the latest tendencies in theory and research raise questions _about_ the past. It seems to me that it does not fit the context well.